# Node looks up at a different path

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I have installed nodejs on my linux terminal. On typing nodejs -v I can see the version of node, but on typing node -v the terminal returns:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

When I search the following:

```
which node
```

I get the following result:

```
/usr/bin/node
```

The command 'node' looks up in a different directory from where it actually is and this also is causing a problem while installing npm.

Please help me out.

Comment: Try [nodejs vs node on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18130164/2873538)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs vs node on ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: @Riddhesh I was thrown the following error: `too many levels of symbolic links`

Comment: for which command, what did you try?

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/node  /usr/local/bin/node I tried this @Riddhesh

Comment: Not sure about the issue. Try out `find -L ./ -mindepth 15` (use appropriate dir) to check if there is any symlink pointing to itself. Another alternative can be that you can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to install node, which can handle multiple versions as well.